# Ada dependency graph

Tags: dictionary, dependencies, ada

I need to create a dependency graph for a software suite that I am working on.  In the past the company I work for has always done this manually, but I am guessing that there is a tool somewhere that will do what we need.

The software I am working with is Ada95, and has about 200 code modules/files, with about 40 packages.  I need to create a map that will trace every output, individually, back to each input or constant that will have an impact on the output.  Does anybody know of a tool that would accomplish this?  Or even just partially accomplish it?

Comment: did you check "ada dependency graph" with google first?

Answer (score 3):

AdaCore's GPS (available from http://libre.adacore.com) comes with a command line tool named `gnatinspect`. You can use this tool to load all cross-reference information generated by the compiler (assuming you are compiling with GNAT). This creates a sqlite database (gnatinspect.db) which contains all information you need. `gnatinspect` itself provides a number of pre-made queries that might get you at least partially to where you want to go.

You could also look at ASIS, as a way to do this kind of queries directly on the code. I am told this is not so easy to use the first time around though.

There is also an older tool provided with gnat (`gnatxref`) which does something similar, although it is being superceded by `gnatinspect`.

Finally, you could look at `gnat2xml` as an alternative to ASIS if you are more comfortable parsing XML files.